# Parse.com limit posts?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, parse-platform

I want users to not be able to add new data or update before a day has passed.  Basically check if user has added anything in the last 24 hours and respond to that.

I am not sure how to do this with cloud code. Check when was the last time the user added their last data and either allow the user to add new data or to prevent them from doing it. Is this the correct way to go about it ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would do this locally on the device. Get the last post that your user posted. Check the updated or created time. Then check if the time now is >= 24 hours after that time.

Comment: Thats what i thought. Still i am looking for alternatives so that i can limit the users ability to get around the check.

Comment: If you're check the latest post on parse.com rather than storing the latest post date/time on device then this is still safe

Comment: I still need to compare the date from parse to the current date, which users can change. Correct? Or am i missing something?

Comment: Yes you're right, they can do that. In that case then yes you can do it in cloudCode. I would use exactly the same process but do it in cloud code